# Gnuplot and arara

Tags: gnuplot, arara

Is there a way to avoid recompiling every single gnuplot figure of a document if it's content hasn't been modified, like it is possible with TikZ when 'externalize' mode is selected?

Each Gnuplot figure is created in an external file:

```
{\footnotesize
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions={pdf size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.4\textwidth} fontscale 0.5 transparent crop}]

here the code of the figure

\end{gnuplot}
}
```

I use arara to build my document with those arguments:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {draft: yes, shell: yes}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: {files: [IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.aux, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.bbl, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.bcf, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.blg, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.log, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.out, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.run.xml, IETpaper_Galvanically_Isolated_Modular_Converter.toc]}
```

Comment: You could put the code for every figure in a seperate .gnuplot file and manually run gnuplot on the scripts.

Comment: Yes but it's not really convenient. Plus it doesn't take advantage of passing to the figures the '\textwidth'.

Comment: You can use something like the printlen package to find \textheight and \textwidth and give these (or a nice fraction of these) as the width or height for you figure. For the a4paper as defined by the geometry package I use:
`set terminal epslatex color solid size 14.70cm, 5.17cm` which is 1/4 the \textheight.